# Decompose Frobenius norm of the difference between 2 matrices

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $B = UDV^T$ where $U\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}$, $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times r}, D\in\mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$ and $U^TU = V^TV = I_r$. Define two sets:
$$S_1=\mathbb{R}^{r\times r}$$
$$S_2 = \{\text{All $r\times r$ diagonal matrices}\}\subset S_1$$
and
$$D_1=\arg\min_{M\in S_1}\|UMV^T - A\|_F^2$$
$$D_2=\arg\min_{M\in S_2}\|UMV^T - A\|_F^2$$
where $\|\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

My questions are:

1. Is this identity true? 
   \begin{align*}
   \|B-A\|_F^2&=\|B - UD_1V^T\|_F^2+\|UD_1V^T-A\|_F^2\\
   &=\|B - UD_2V^T\|_F^2+\|UD_2V^T-A\|_F^2
   \end{align*}
2. Can we express $\|UD_1V^T-A\|_F^2$ and $\|UD_2V^T-A\|_F^2$ explicitly as functions of $U,V,A$?

Comment: Is $D$ (defining $B$) a diagonal matrix as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Note that the Frobenius norm 
   $$ 
   || X + Y ||_{F}^2 = tr\left( (X+Y)^T (X+Y) \right)
   = || X ||_{F}^2 + 2 tr\left( X^T Y \right) + || Y ||_{F}^2
   $$
   The minimization (defining $D_1$) yields that
   $$ 
   tr\left( (UD_1 V^T - A)^T (U M V^T ) \right) = 0
   $$
   for any matrix $M$ in $S_1$.
   Next write
   $$
   ‖−‖_F^2 = ||B - UD_1 V^T ||_F^2 + 2 tr\left( (UD_1 V^T - A)^T (B - UD_1 V^T ) \right) + || U D_1 V^T - A ||_F^2 
   $$
   The middle term is $0$ because $B - UD_1 V^T = U( D - D_1 )V^T$.
2. Write
   $$ 
   || U D V^T - A ||_{F}^2 = || U ( D - U^T A V ) V^T ||_{F}^2
   = || D - U^T A V ||_{F}^2
   $$
   So we get $D_1 = U^T A V$ and $D_2$ is the diagonal part of $U^T A V$.